# What .NET time series libraries are there?

Tags: .net, time

I am looking for a .NET library for time series work. It can be either free or commercial. My basic requirements are the following:

- Handle time series in varying frequencies (daily, business daily, week ending Friday, monthly, quarterly, annual, etc).
- Convert between different calendar frequencies, going from both high to low frequency and low to high frequency.
- Supporting time series transformations like moving averages, annualized percent changes, etc.
- Allowing time series to be combined together; for instance time series A = B+sqrt(C)

Comment: A couple of questions, how would one calculate the SQRT(monthly) also how would this be used?

Comment: Lazarus - The SQRT() call I put in there was just to demonstrate that I want to be able to use standard mathematical functions in my formulas. The time series is just an array of numbers, so the function runs on each number. 

The basic use case for this type of library is working with economic data. You might have monthly retail sales, daily oil prices, quarterly GDP, etc. You might want to sum quarterly GDP readings to annual, take monthly percent changes of retail sales, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[TimeSeriesDB](http://code.google.com/p/timeseriesdb/) library is designed to store huge strongly-typed timeseries with a customizable compression. The result is a generic IEnumerable that can be fed into any statistics library. (Disclaimer: posted by the lib's author)

Comment: Sadly the project seems dead :(

Answer (score 1):

High peformance time series persistence in flat files is covered by

https://github.com/discretelogics/TeaFiles.Net

I am a founder of discretelogics providing this library.

Comment: Sadly the project seems dead :(

Comment: why do you believe so?

Comment: No commits in 5 years, a pr that has been there for a few years

Comment: well, it still works, no bugs are reported and issues are replied to and processed. finally it is open source. it is still usefull to many

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Deedle](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/) for manipulation of time series in C# and F#.

> Deedle is an easy to use library for data and time series manipulation and for scientific programming. It supports working with structured data frames, ordered and unordered data, as well as time series. Deedle is designed to work well for exploratory programming using F# and C# interactive console, but can be also used in efficient compiled .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

There is another library "**ThinkSharpTimeFlow**" which is focused on time series (no data frame as Deedle) and designed for C#.

https://github.com/JanDotNet/Thinksharp.TimeFlow

It can also be used within .Net Interactive Jupiter Notebooks!

See the that [jupiter notebook](https://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/JanDotNet/Thinksharp.TimeFlow/blob/f5b7ba0ddf711b0f94e1e71dc903bd9865f9eb3a/Notebooks/timeseries.ipynb) for usage.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library.